# Trouble adding graphics to planes

Tags: modeling

I have been trying to add graphics to rectangular planes in blender. i have had success when doing so on planes generated in blender but not with ones generated externally. my workflow for the blender polygons is to simply create a new material with an image texture as the base colour and to import my graphic (with the same dimensions). this works fine. when i try to do this with the imported polygon it doesnt work. i tried unwrapping the plane in the UV editor (with the imported graphic selected but despite the uv appearing to overlay correctly on the graphic, it is rotated 90degrees (and so distorted) in the 3d view. could anyone point out where i am going wrong please? thanks!

[image]

Comment: maybe share your file (just the object with the problem)?

Comment: Hi there, could you please explain what software you use to "create" your plane, what file format is used etc.? Also adding screenshots and blend file of both Blender and that software showing your process would help the viewer understand the problem.

Comment: thanks for replys. ive added a screenshot showing how the graphic appears on both planes. left plane is the blender plane and the right side is the uv unwrapped imported plane. both are identical size and have the same number of edges so i would have thought they would behave the same. the software i use is Rhino 3d and i have been exporting the mesh as .STL.
(im not sure how i would share the .blend file...)